positive integer triples for $a^{(b-c)} = 22b + 1$
(Q) Prove that there are infinitely many  positive integer triples $(a,b,c)$ with $(a,b,c)>0$ satisfying$$a^{(b-c)} = 22b + 1$$
My Attempt
I've been working on this problem where I need to find integer triples $(a, b, c)$ that satisfy a particular equation.
So far, I've successfully identified three pairs that work, but I'm struggling to find more.
Here's what I have so far:

$(3,11,6)$
$(45,2,1)$
$(67,3,2)$

To find these pairs, I've been using the technique of plugging in small values of $b$ and then solving for $a$ and $c$. Specifically, the key is to set $b$ to an integer, calculate $22b + 1$, and then check if that number can be expressed as $a^{(b-c)}$. This usually involves trial and error to match $a$ with an appropriate $c$.
However, I'm hitting a wall when it comes to finding additional pairs. If anyone has experience with this kind of problem or can suggest a more systematic approach to generate more solutions, I'd really appreciate the help!

With your current stated conditions, there are an infinite number of solutions with, for example, $b\gt 1$, $a=22b+1$ and $c=b-1$. Another example with an infinite number of solutions is, for any integer $d\ge 1$, having $a=22d+1$, $b=22d^2+2d$ and $c=b-2$.

You found three "pairs", and were struggling to find more. User @John found you infinitely many. That deserves some appreciation, and some thought.

Let $a$ be any number prime to $22$. Let $r$ be any number such that $a^r\equiv1\bmod{22}$. So $a^r=22b+1$ for some $b$. Then let $c=b-r$.

@Grey:  Fermat's little theorem guarantees such an $r$ exists when $a$ is coprime to $22$.  Any multiple of $r$ will also work.

In fact, it is better to fix $a$ and solve for $b$ and $c$. Following the method of @Gerry Myerson, we can actually find all working triples. First of all, if $a^{b - c} = 22b + 1$, then $b \geqslant c$. If $b = c$, we must have $b = 0$ which is not allowed hence $b > c$. Let $d = b - c > 0$. In this case, we have $a \cdot a^{d - 1} - 22b = 1$ so by Bézout theorem, $a$ and $22$ are coprime.
Fix $a$ coprime to $22$. For all $d$, there is a $b$ such that $a^d = 22b + 1$ if and only if $a^d \equiv 1\ [22]$. Let $\omega(a)$ be the smallest positive integer such that $a^{\omega(a)} \equiv 1\ [22]$. By Fermat's little theorem, $\omega(a)$ is well-defined and it divides $\varphi(22) = 22 \cdot (1 - 1/2) \cdot (1 - 1/11) = 10$. so $\omega(a) \in \{1,2,5,10\}$. This number only depends on the class of $a$ modulo $22$. We can simply compute that,
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a \mod 22 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 13 & 15 & 17 & 19 & 21\\
\hline
\omega(a) & 1 & 5 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 2\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Then, for all integer $d$, $a^d \equiv 1\ [22]$ if and only if $\omega(a)|d$. We also need $b = c + d$ to be greater than $d$ so $c$ is positive. It means that we need that,
$$
b = \frac{a^d - 1}{22} > d.
$$
thus, the set of all solutions is,
\begin{align*}
S & = \Biggl\{\left(a,\frac{a^{k\omega(a)} - 1}{22},\frac{a^{k\omega(a)} - 1}{22} - k\omega(a)\right)\biggl|\\
& \ \ \ \ a > 0, a \wedge 22 = 1, k > 0, a^{k\omega(a)} > 22k\omega(a) + 1\Biggl\}.
\end{align*}
Notice that the condition $a^{k\omega(a)} > 22k\omega(a) + 1$ is verified for all $k$ when $a$ is large enough and for all $a$ when $k$ is large enough so only a finite number of triples is excluded because of this condition.
